# CSS - Position element above others and in the middle of screen

Tags: css, element, center, cover

I want to position a div in the middle of the screen, above all other elements so it makes them unclickable and covers them with its background.

```
.myElement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
}
```

So far, I have only managed to center the element. However, the white background does not cover the whole screen, it covers 1/4 of the screen and it does allow for the other elements below it to be clicked.

I am new to .css styling so I would be glad if someone could help me achieve the wanted result.

Comment: top:0; left:0 ?

Comment: "in the middle of the screen" but "above all other elements" and "covers them". Do you want it 100% wide? Please post some screenshot and the html markup

Comment: @TemaniAfif, this positions my element in the top left corner.

Comment: @DaFois, That pretty much sums up how I want it yes.

Comment: @Smitherson so you want 2 divs: one as overlay above the other elements and one centered horizontally and vertically on screen. Is it correct?

Comment: You are looking for Modal actually, if you are using Bootstrap then please go through the Bootstrap Modal document or search for the custom modal.

Comment: Just set the `top`, `left`, `position` and `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#607d8b;
}
.content h1{
  margin:auto;
  color:#fff;
}
.overlay{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  position:fixed;
  top:25%;
  left:25%;
  z-index:100;
  background-color:#becbd2;
  text-align:center;
}

/*or if you want to use a static values do this:*/

/*.overlay{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:fixed;
  top:25%;
  margin-top:-100px //Half of height;
  left:25%;
  margin-left:-100px //Half of width;
  z-index:100;
  background-color:#becbd2;
  text-align:center;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Page content</h1>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
  <h1>Overlay content</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @TemaniAfif mentioned, firstly make `top: 0; left: 0;` followed by setting the `width: 100%; height: 100%;`. This will set your `height` and `width` attribute of the div to its container size (which in this case is the `body`).

Here is your code:

```css
.hiddenDiv {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    background: blue;
}

.myElement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class = hiddenDiv>
This div is hidden
</div>

<div class = myElement>
This is a cover
</div>
```